# JavaScript - count occurrence of strings

Tags: javascript, json

I'm looking to count the occurances of certain strings within JSON - in this instance `sensorUUID`.

```
var newDataArray = JSON.stringify(conData);
```

JSON

```
[{"blobJson":"x","deviceMfg":10,"eventCode":0,"sensorClass":3,"sensorUUID":"22489710","timeStamp":1500362037.111941,"uID":"22489710_3_10"},{"blobJson":"x","deviceMfg":10,"eventCode":0,"sensorClass":3,"sensorUUID":"22489710","timeStamp":1500362036.109874,"uID":"22489710_3_10"}]
```

I've tried the following code but it is returning an empty object.

```
var obj = {};

for (var i = 0, j = newDataArray.length; i < j; i++) {
  if (obj[newDataArray[i].sensorUUID]) {
    obj[newDataArray[i]]++;
  }
}

console.log(obj);
```

The full JSON file will have multiple sensor ID's within it, I am looking to return the number of unique sensor ID.

e.g.

22489710 has 10 occurrences

63846683 has 23 occurrences

etc.

Comment: which string? sensorUUID?

Comment: Yes, I'll update my question.

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: I'm looking to count the number of occurrences as the JSON will have multiple sensor ID's.

Comment: you should try to use Object.hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the if condition in for loop is correct but you have to initialize count as 1 for the first time you find a particular sensorUUID.

```js
var newDataArray = [{"blobJson":"x","deviceMfg":10,"eventCode":0,"sensorClass":3,"sensorUUID":"22489710","timeStamp":1500362037.111941,"uID":"22489710_3_10"},{"blobJson":"x","deviceMfg":10,"eventCode":0,"sensorClass":3,"sensorUUID":"22489710","timeStamp":1500362036.109874,"uID":"22489710_3_10"}];

var obj = {};
for (var i = 0, j = newDataArray.length; i < j; i++) {
  if (obj[newDataArray[i].sensorUUID]) {
     obj[newDataArray[i].sensorUUID]++;
  }else{
     obj[newDataArray[i].sensorUUID] = 1;
  }
}
// obj gives you count for each unique sensorUUID.
console.log(obj);

//if you want total count of all sensorUUID you can sum all the values in obj.
var count = Object.values(obj).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
console.log(count);
```

Comment: I'm running into a problem, your code returns `{22255750: 61, undefined: 2}` - the total number for `22255750` is `63` and it is not reporting anything for `19455746`

Comment: How come there is 4 statements in the `for` loop? I've not seen this before.

Comment: this means `obj[newDataArray[i].sensorUUID]` is returning `undefined`, is sensorUUID the correct string?

Comment: I checked the JSON and it is `sensorUUID`

Comment: well structure of your array must be different from the sample array given in question, otherwise it will not give wrong result.

Comment: I had a look at the full data file and it looks like `newDataArray` is actually make up of multiple JSON arrays

Comment: yeah so it will have to be fixed for that.

Comment: What would need changed?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply iterate through the `json` array using `array.reduce` and `count` the occurances of `sensorUUID` and store it inside the new object.

```js
var json = [{
  "blobJson": "x",
  "deviceMfg": 10,
  "eventCode": 0,
  "sensorClass": 3,
  "sensorUUID": "22489710",
  "timeStamp": 1500362037.111941,
  "uID": "22489710_3_10"
}, {
  "blobJson": "x",
  "deviceMfg": 10,
  "eventCode": 0,
  "sensorClass": 3,
  "sensorUUID": "22489710",
  "timeStamp": 1500362037.111941,
  "uID": "22489710_3_10"
}, {
  "blobJson": "x",
  "deviceMfg": 10,
  "eventCode": 0,
  "sensorClass": 3,
  "sensorUUID": "22489710123",
  "timeStamp": 1500362036.109874,
  "uID": "22489710_3_10"
}];

let count = json.reduce((newObj, obj) => {
  if(newObj[obj.sensorUUID]) {
    newObj[obj.sensorUUID] = newObj[obj.sensorUUID]+1;
  } else {
    newObj[obj.sensorUUID] = 1;
  }
  return newObj;
}, {});

console.log(count);
```

Comment: That is returning - `TypeError: newDataArray.forEach is not a function`

Comment: I have used the json you have provided. You should update your question with the value you are using for newDataArray.

Answer (score 0):

you can set a variable count and iterate over the array using [Array#forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and check whether the object has the property *sensorUUID* using [Object#hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) if yes, increment the count

```js
var data = [{"blobJson":"x","deviceMfg":10,"eventCode":0,"sensorClass":3,"sensorUUID":"22489710","timeStamp":1500362037.111941,"uID":"22489710_3_10"},{"blobJson":"x","deviceMfg":10,"eventCode":0,"sensorClass":3,"sensorUUID":"22489710","timeStamp":1500362036.109874,"uID":"22489710_3_10"}];
var count = 0;
data.forEach((x)=>{
  if(x.hasOwnProperty('sensorUUID'))
    count++;
});
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/7jjoches/1/

Using jquery method $.parseJSON you have to convert the JSON string to a JSON object and only then you can work with it.

```js
var conData = '[{"blobJson":"x","deviceMfg":10,"eventCode":0,"sensorClass":3,"sensorUUID":"22489710","timeStamp":1500362037.111941,"uID":"22489710_3_10"},{"blobJson":"x","deviceMfg":10,"eventCode":0,"sensorClass":3,"sensorUUID":"22489710","timeStamp":1500362036.109874,"uID":"22489710_3_10"}]';

var newDataArray = $.parseJSON(conData);

console.dir(newDataArray);

var obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i< newDataArray.length; i++) {
    obj[newDataArray[i].sensorUUID] = obj[newDataArray[i].sensorUUID] ? obj[newDataArray[i].sensorUUID]+1 : 1;
}

console.log(obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```